# How to align a select element vertically with input text?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/Lztqo0va/

HTML

```
<select>
<option>lorem ipsum</option>
</select>
<input type="text" value="lorem ipsum"/>
```

CSS

```
select, input{
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

I'd like the select element to be aligned vertically to the input one. Is this possible without changing their display attribute? Even if I do change the attribute the text inside the select is still off-center vertically.

Comment: remove the padding off the elements directly - if you need padding, use wrapping <div>'s to control space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either remove the padding and add only left padding or increase the height of the box itself.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lztqo0va/3/

```
select, input{
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To vertically align the two tags, you could use the `vertical-align: middle` css attribute. Notice that you should reduce the `font-size` of the select tag to have the text to fit in.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lztqo0va/1/

Comment: This still makes the text itself not aligned. It was the padding, as Andyjm said.